# How hard I should push myself?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, cardio, gym

How hard I should push myself?

I started to enjoy pushing my limits, thankfully :) I use elliptical cycle for cardio for at least 30 mins a day.

On average I use it at level 8/8, with 14kmh and about 160HR. At the end, for 5 to 15 minutes, I go faster at 16~ and I feel like it's almost impossible to continue. I sortof feel like losing myself physically. I avoid pain in my muscles. When I absualtely have to stop, I stop. I don't use HR but I suppose at that point I'm around 180 or more when I use my hand to count.

Occasionally, I feel like my heart stops beating or slows down for a few seconds on random times. Maybe once a week. But I feel good. Maybe that's related and is saying me to stop pushing?

I'm 100kg, m, 22, taking 1500-2000cal daily. My BMR: 1700.

The answer should be in terms of how hard I should push myself in terms of HR, feeling and post cardio effects.

Comment: Push yourself until you collapse. Or don't. Nobody can tell you how hard you should push yourself. Hence the phrase "Push yourself".

Comment: How did you calculate your BMR? Using an online calculator (http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/bmr_calculator.htm) the only way to get to 1700 with the other stats you provided is if you are 2' 8" inches tall.

Comment: Used a machine in a facility. The exact number was 1760 or something. I have 35% bf

Answer (score 2):

With weight training, find a program (I do 5/3/1) and follow it exactly.

In other words, you find a program (there are many, many programs), be honest about your lifting numbers, and progress just as it says from there.

With cardio, no more than an hour really makes sense - you have to live a little, and pumping away on a treadmill for more than an hour will take your motivation away to workout lightning quick. Personally, I do, at most, 30 minutes of cardio - for weight-loss, you want to be burning more calories than you use.  That means that cardio can be a means to an end, but it is not necessary to lose a lot of weight in short order.

Lastly, you're 100kg and a man, you should be having somewhere between 2000 and 2500 calories, 1500 really doesn't cut it and you will burn out in short order. I'm 95kg, about 6'2" and trying a 1500 calorie diet really hamstringed my efforts of shedding a few pounds.  The key is maintainability - you cannot maintain eating 1500 calories a day, but 2000 is far more doable.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 for finding a *successful and proven program* and *sticking to it*. Too many people confuse routines with programs, or don't follow the plan, then wonder why they're not getting the results they want.

Comment: You either didn't read my BMR or don't know what that means. Or am I missing something here? To lose 1kg a week my intake should be 1500 a day.

Comment: Well don't get defensive, by all means eat 1500, but you will probably lose some muscle and you'll find yourself feeling a little more depressed than usual, but your mileage may vary!